# Use InputStreamReader twice

Tags: java, utf-8, character-encoding, inputstream

I have to check a file's encoding before reading it. To check the encoding, I use this method:

```
        try {
            CharsetDecoder decoder= Charset.forName("UTF-8").newDecoder();
            decoder.onMalformedInput(CodingErrorAction.REPORT);
            decoder.onUnmappableCharacter(CodingErrorAction.REPORT);
            final InputStreamReader input = new InputStreamReader(is, decoder);
            int data = input.read();
            while(data != -1){
                data = input.read();
            }
            input.close();
        } catch (MalformedInputException e) {
            LOGGER.error(The file encoding is wrong!");
            throw new MalformedInputException(Math.toIntExact(file.length()));
        }
    }
```

And here is the code that calls it:

```
    InputStream is = new FileInputStream(file);
    checkFileEncoding(is);

    List<MyObject> list = newArrayList();
    try(CSVReader reader = new CSVReader(new InputStreamReader(is), ';')) {
        list =  reader.readAll().stream()
                .skip(1) // 
                .map(myObjectMap)
                .filter(o -> o != null)
                .collect(toList());
    }
```

The thing is, my list is empty when I call `checkFileEncoding` before. I think it's because I read my file twice. How should I do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
final InputStreamReader input = new InputStreamReader(is, decoder);
```

Your InputStreamReader will read all the data from the input stream. This means there is no data available anymore. In addition you already close it.

You will need to create a InputStream two times. One time to test the character set and one more time to actually read the data.

So change

```
InputStream is = new FileInputStream(file);
checkFileEncoding(is);
```

to

```
InputStream is = new FileInputStream(file);
checkFileEncoding(is);
is = new FileInputStream(file);
```

Also after the

```
try(CSVReader reader ..
..
}
```

add

```
is.close();
```

Answer (score 0):

try [Guess Encoding](http://central.maven.org/maven2/org/codehaus/guessencoding/guessencoding/1.4/guessencoding-1.4.jar) library.

```
Charset charset = CharsetToolkit.guessEncoding(file, 4096, StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
```

This should return you the expected result.

I tried it against a `HTML` file and the result was `US-ASCII` as charset.

you may try [Any23](http://central.maven.org/maven2/org/apache/any23/apache-any23-core/1.1/apache-any23-core-1.1.jar) library

```
Charset charset = Charset.forName(new TikaEncodingDetector().guessEncoding(new FileInputStream(file)));
```

Comment: Thanks for the tip!